# php.ini file edit issue

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

my WordPress  and PHP is working fine but I need to edit the php.ini file and add the below 2 lines

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension = oci8.so
```

But when I add the 2 lines  and restarted I got the below error

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

when I removed those 2 lines it is working fine. can someone please help?

Note : I am using Cent OS env

Comment: Try removing the `extension=php_oci8.dll` line.   That is for Windows.

Comment: I removed it but I got the same error

Comment: Do you have a file called `oci8.so` on the system?   Where is it located?

Comment: I added this line as the last line in the file  extension=php_oci8.dll

Comment: I am not sure where is  oci8.so is located I have '20-oci8.ini; file

Comment: Try `find / -type f -name "oci8.so"`

Comment: yes I have the file here /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so

Comment: Make sure that the `php.ini` directive `extension_dir` is set to the directory that `oci8.so` is installed in, i.e. `/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so`

Comment: Now I am not getting that error but now  when I do php--version I get the below error

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8 (/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so

Comment: Did you build your PHP yourself?  If so, modify your configure command to include the mysql libraries and recompile.

Comment: it is wordpress installation